# How can I get the document status with a javascript application or CMIS In Alfresco

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-maven

how can I get the document status with Javascript application or CMIS. I mean if it was approved or rejected in a Workflow.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an out-of-the-box workflow, I don't know of an easy way to get that information because the out-of-the-box workflows do not change any properties on the documents in the workflow package.

You could modify the workflow to set a property on the document. Then you'd be able to check that property to determine what happened in the workflow.

See [this tutorial](http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/workflow/tutorial/tutorial.html) for an example that does this.